# HTML5 Input Type Number 16 Digits or More Chrome Replaces with Zeroes

Tags: html, google-chrome, forms

Has anyone else experienced a problem with Chrome when using an input type of number and the number of digits exceeds 16? In my situation, anything after the 16th digit is being replaced with a zero on blur. This doesn't occur in the other browsers.

```
<label for="some-number-input">Number Input</label>
<input type="number" name="some-number-input" id="some-number-input" />
```

Is there a solution to this other than changing the input type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the number input is blurred, Chrome parses the number. According to the [WHATWG standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#number-state-%28type=number%29), it should convert it to an IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point number, just like the way numbers are represented in JavaScript. And also like in JavaScript, there's a limit to the precision that these numbers can have, hence the rounding.

You might want to use `<input type="text">` instead..

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am trying to stay away from using input type text because I want the numeric keypad to appear on mobile. Input type tel works in that it doesn't round, but it's not semantically correct, plus it shows the letters over the numeric keypad. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Are you sure input type number is semantically correct, either? If you're entering an ID number or something I'm pretty sure that's not correct. If you just want the numeric keypad another post says that [you can set the pattern attribute for iOS devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178556/iphone-numeric-keyboard-for-text-input) but I don't know if that works elsewhere.

Comment: You're right, looks like I am not using the number type correctly based on the spec. Sigh, and it would seem that pattern "\d*" does not work on Android. Looks like there is currently no way to force numeric keypad for long ID numbers.