# iPhone: numeric keyboard for credit card input

Tags: html, iphone

Currently I'm using 
`<input type="text">`

If I use `<input type="number">`, the problem is that in Chrome the input field starts to look like this, with up and down arrows:

[image: image of input field with up and down arrows]

Is there a better solution?

Comment: try `<input type="text" pattern="\d*">` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178556/iphone-numeric-keyboard-for-text-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your css file to remove the arrows.

```
form input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
form input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
-webkit-appearance: none;
margin: 0;
}
```

Source:
http://thanewoidan.com/articles/14/hide-default-input-type-number-up-down-arrows-in-chrome

Hope that helps you!