# ionic 2 differentiate between input types based on platform

Tags: html, ionic2

I am writing an application using ionic where I have an input field that must take a positive integer number. I have looked up the types [here](http://ionicframework.com/html5-input-types/)

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input #input type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" [(ngModel)]="..." pattern="[0-9]" required placeholder="Access Code"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Now my problem is that on iOS the numeric input is the FULL numbered keyboard (I can use mathematical symbols). For iOS I want to use the

> tel

type but for android I want to keep the

> number

input type. Is there a way I can do this without making 2 separate html pages for each platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this:
[Phone: numeric keyboard for text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178556/phone-numeric-keyboard-for-text-input)

I need to have the input like this:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

Which has produced the correct results. I was missing the asterisk.

Answer (score 3):

As shown by the [Ionic Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/), you can add this to your TS file:

```
 import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

 constructor(platform: Platform) {
      this.platform = platform;
 }
```

Then.. in your html, use 'ngIf' to check whether the platform is android or IoS:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input *ngIf="platform.is('android')" #input type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" [(ngModel)]="..." pattern="[0-9]" required placeholder="Access Code"></ion-input>
    <ion-input *ngIf="platform.is('ios')" #input type="tel" min="0" inputmode="numeric" [(ngModel)]="..." pattern="[0-9]" required placeholder="Access Code"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for this! I did find that I could get the numeric keypad by including the pattern=[0-9]* and then I can use the same input type.

Comment: Yeah makes sense, much neater solution

Comment: Well, I'd suggest you to use `showWhen` or `hideWhen` directive(s), so you don't need to import nothing in your **TS** file.