# Is there material input type number in angular 2 dart

Tags: dart, material-design, angular-dart, angular-components

I was tring to use material component in angular 2 dart as a number input:

```
<material-input type="number"></material-input>
```

but it behaves like a normal input. In docs it sais it supports type "number". Am i doing anything wrong? Or isn't number type implemented yet?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: It really sucks that they do not have a solution for this :-/ Found anything working so far?

Answer (score 3):

I can share my personal experiment trying to have a number (integer) input. It does not work perfectly on all browsers but I wanted to have the proper keyboard shown on Android and iOS. What I did was forcing the type on the inner input element programmatically. It seems that on Firefox it does not prevent entering text but does display a message ("Please enter a number"). It does not handle decimal neither (i.e. it does expect an integer)

```
initInputNumber(MaterialInputComponent inputComponent) {
    inputComponent.type = "number";
    InputElement inputElement = inputComponent.inputEl.nativeElement;
    inputElement.type = "number";

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178556/phone-numeric-keyboard-for-text-input
    // As of mid-2015, I believe this is the best solution:
    //  <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
    inputElement.attributes["inputmode"] = "numeric";
    inputElement.pattern = "[0-9]*"; // this and only this works 0-9
  }
```

I don't know if that's the best solution but I find it hard to have a complete cross-browser solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set an `errorMsg`

```
<material-input type="number" errorMsg="That's not a number"></material-input>
```

This line https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components/blob/a0eff879a6cb347b8beb95ed758c02c6dd9dfaa0/lib/src/components/material_input/material_input.dart#L232 seems to indicate that `type="tel"` and `type="number"` are set to `text` for the internal input element, while this line https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components/blob/a0eff879a6cb347b8beb95ed758c02c6dd9dfaa0/lib/src/components/material_input/material_input.dart#L61 says that `errorMsg` is used when and invalid number is entered when `type="number"`.

Comment: Your solutions does not work.

I tried to copy the appropriate files from the library, edited imports and critical lines - then error messages and not being eble to write letter works.

What i have not achieved are the little arrow keys, like in standart html5  <input type="number" /> or like in angularjs [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input) (second block, "hourly rate in USD)

Comment: Sorry, no idea.