# how to open numeric keyboard in tablet for input type text

Tags: android, jquery, ios

My code look like this

```
<div id="example4" class="autotabbed">
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' maxlength="1" class="adr_dgt autotabbed" size="1" placeholder="x" />
</div>
```

when I open this in tablet how to get numeric keypad

Comment: I tried `pattern = '[0-9]'` but it is not working for manual entering.it works only for upper and lower arrow key press

Comment: [Please check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178556/phone-numeric-keyboard-for-text-input/31619311#31619311) This could help you!

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
input type="number"
```

That should work

Comment: Thanks for your help @ArtiChoke .But i want solution for input type text

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="example4" class="autotabbed">
  <input type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' maxlength="1" class="adr_dgt autotabbed" size="1" placeholder="x" />
</div>
```

On focus this will open the numeric keypad on tablets and phones.

Comment: here the maxlength and size attribute's are not working.These two is working fine for type text only

Comment: use <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5"> and add style for width  instead of size.