# How to allow "0." decimal in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery. I have a form with two input boxes. In that i am implemented some validations.

```
<form>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group ">
  <label for="minAmt" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Min.Amount</label>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control minAmt" id="minAmt" name="minAmt" placeholder="Enter Min Amount" />
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="form-group ">
  <label for="maxAmt" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Max.Amount</label>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control maxAmt" id="maxAmt" name="maxAmt" placeholder="Enter Max Amount" />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-actions btnzone">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success savebtn" style="padding: 6px 12px;margin-left: 40%;" id="addbutton" ><i class="icon-check-sign" aria-hidden="false"></i>Add</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Script code here:

```
$('#minAmt,#maxAmt').keyup(function(){
    // if($(this).val() == '0'){
      //$(this).val('');  
    //}
     var val = this.value;
      var re = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)$/g;
      var re1 = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)/g;
      if (re.test(val)) {
        //do something here

      } else {
        val = re1.exec(val);
        if (val) {
          this.value = val[0];
        } else {
          this.value = "";
        }
      }
   });
```

Here i am allowing first value `0` and decimal value allowing up to `two` points only.

But here some cases wrong input's taking. For Example i enter `0500` or `0000555` etc.. it allowing starting with `0`,that's why previously i restricted `0` doesn't allow first character but it is effected to decimal values starts with `0` (`0.01` or `0.98`) are not allowing.

My requirement is `money` related. So i want change to `0000555` to `555`.

How to modify my  code?

Comment: you are not able to click `.` in your number input field. so how 0.10 will came?

Comment: why use both `$(this).val()` and the (correct) `this.value` ?

Comment: @Alnitak neither are any more "correct" than the other. One is just the jQuery wrapper.

Comment: @Alive to Die: i am able to click `.` please check carefully

Comment: Your question is *really* unclear. Both your regular expressions match `0.` - it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Try explaining that.

Comment: Do you really need the block: `if($(this).val() == '0') {  $(this).val(''); }` It seems like it would cause problems in a `keyup` scenario for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Jamiec one involves several function calls (including the ones internal to jQuery).  The other requires a trivial property lookup.

Comment: @Alnitak that doesnt make one "correct" - it might make one "faster" or "more efficient"

Comment: @Jamiec perhaps, but I regard use of things like `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `this.id` a pretty bad jQuery code smell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to solve your problem:

```js
$('#minAmt,#maxAmt').keyup(function(){
  // if($(this).val() == '0'){
    //$(this).val('');  
  //}
  var val = this.value;
  // <new code>
  if(val.length > 1 
     && val.indexOf('0') === 0 
     && val.indexOf('.') === -1){
   this.value = this.value.substring(1);
  }
  // </new code>
  var re = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)$/g;
  var re1 = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)/g;
  if (re.test(val)) {
    //do something here

  } else {
    val = re1.exec(val);
    if (val) {
      this.value = val[0];
    } else {
      this.value = "";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group ">
  <label for="minAmt" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Min.Amount</label>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control minAmt" id="minAmt" name="minAmt" placeholder="Enter Min Amount" />
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="form-group ">
  <label for="maxAmt" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Max.Amount</label>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control maxAmt" id="maxAmt" name="maxAmt" placeholder="Enter Max Amount" />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-actions btnzone">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success savebtn" style="padding: 6px 12px;margin-left: 40%;" id="addbutton" ><i class="icon-check-sign" aria-hidden="false"></i>Add</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

It doesn't use a fancy regex but it works.

P.S. You should also validate the inputs server-side, 'cause people can get around javascript. I'm saying it just in case, maybe you already do it.

Comment: Thank you saved my day. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try input type='number' with step

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control"  />
```

Comment: @Durga: Be careful because if you change your input type to "number" your code in the "keyup" event won't work properly in android (I dunno about iOS). Check out This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761396/minus-sign-and-dot-clear-input-type-number-field-with-replace/43761516#43761516

Answer (score 0):

just used

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control minAmt" id="minAmt" name="minAmt" placeholder="Enter Min Amount" />
```

and validation will be automatically

But if you need uses regexp, you can use this construction for validation float type like 0.01 or 0,01:

```
var template = /^([-+]?[0-9]*[\.|,]?[0-9]*)$/g
val = template.test(val) ? parseFloat(val, 2) : 0; // after this row val any way will be some float positive or negative or 0, but we can operate it like number
```

Second row transform any string like number to number without leads 0. For example:

```
var a = '003';
b = parseFloat(a, 2);
// result 3
```

So your code will be like this:

```
$('#minAmt,#maxAmt').keyup(function(){
    var template = /^([-+]?[0-9]*[\.|,]?[0-9]*)$/g
    this.value = template.test(this.value) ? parseFloat(this.value.replace(',', '.'), 2) : 0; //after your field will have the number without leads 0
   });
```

Comment: @Durga: See my comment on Dhaval's answer (which is basically the same).

Comment: @nonzaprej: yes, i observed