# ng-pattern is not considering if starting number is zero in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have to validate the brazil phone no, in brazil phone can be started with zero and it will be 8 digits 
I have given `<input type="number" name="mobileNo" ng-model="booking.phone" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{8,8}$/" required placeholder="Phone no">`

validation is working fine if i given something like "25869859"
But if i have given as "02587895" it is not counting the first number if it is start with zero, it is taking 9 digits 
what is need is it should take only 8 digits even if i given number starting with zero

Comment: Try to change input type to text

Comment: It is ionic cordova mobile app if i changed input type as text then the text keyboard will pop up

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178556/phone-numeric-keyboard-for-text-input

Answer (score 1):

Try change the Quantifier: `^[0-9]{8,9}$`

Quantifier - {8,9}  Matches between 8 and 9 times

Or if you want to verify `0`, try:

```
 ^0?[0-9]{8,8}$
```

`0?` matches the character 0 literally between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

---

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a1szavgv/)</kbd>