# Get a backslash into input created by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an input with JS.
I want the input to show the numeric keyboard after clicking. You'll achieve it by giving the input `pattern="\d*"` so I tried:

```
div.innerHTML = '<input pattern="\d*" class="input-mark" type="number" placeholder="randomPlaceholder" step="1" min="1" max="5">';
```

As you guessed, doesn't work. I tried everything. Giving more slashes and backslashes, nothing worked.

I assume it's easy - but I couldn't figure it out.

ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: `numeric keyboard` on mobile device?

Comment: The `pattern` attribute is used to validate the input value, it doesn't change the keyboard displayed on mobile devices.

Comment: @Mr.x Yes, on mobile.

Comment: @fubar I know, thanks, but it also changes the eyboard to numeric on mobile phones. It DOES work

Comment: <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">

Comment: duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178556/phone-numeric-keyboard-for-text-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` in `\d` to get the `\` in the result. See the corrected code below.

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<input pattern="\\d*" class="input-mark" type="number" placeholder="randomPlaceholder" step="1" min="1" max="5">';

console.log('<input pattern="\\d*" class="input-mark" type="number" placeholder="randomPlaceholder" step="1" min="1" max="5">');
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

This would work.

Comment: Well, I tried this, but it doesn't for me. Sorry :/

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried it on my console and it did work.

Comment: This works fine, see the snippet. I think you need to try again @David. +1 to this answer.

Comment: @Vivek yes, nothing. Go ahead, take a look:

http://uidave.com/prumer/

maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @DavidStančík I see it on your website , maybe your script cached, use CTRL+F5

Comment: @DavidStančík  I have put the code in this answer to jsfiddle. Try opening it in your mobile device. https://jsfiddle.net/utraox8z/

Comment: yep, script cashed. Works great. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is to define the input pattern. You will have to use `inputmode` in conjunction with this.

```
 <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

Comment: Without the `pattern`, without `inputmode` it should work because the `type number`, the problem here is `slash`. This is not really answer of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var x = document.createElement( 'input' ),
    div = document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' )[0]; // Just assuming

x.className = 'input-mark';
x.setAttribute( 'type', 'number' );
x.setAttribute( 'placeholder', 'randomPlaceholder' );
x.setAttribute( 'step', 1 );
x.setAttribute( 'min', 1 );
x.setAttribute( 'max', 5 );
x.setAttribute( 'pattern', '\\d*' );
div.appendChild( x );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mu9s2m24/