# Handling number input with Redux Form does strange things

Tags: html, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Using the age field on https://redux-form.com/7.2.1/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/ as an example.

You can enter numbers, +, - and e.  Like below:

[image]

But it doesn't look like Redux Form recognizes those inputs.  If you try to use the parse or normalize lifecycle methods, the value comes through as ''.

Also as in the screenshot the validation says the field is required, as if it is empty.

Is there a way to handle these?

Comment: The only way I have found to eliminate this is to add a keyDown listener on the input field.  It doesn't feel that clean though.

Answer (score 5):

The easies way to handle it is use `parse` like that:

```
<Field
    name="age"
    type="number"
    component={renderField}
    label="Age"
    validate={[required, number, minValue18]}
    warn={tooOld}
    parse={(val) => parseInt(val, 10)}
  />
```

But `parse` function should be mach more smarter than in this example =)

P.S. Don't forget, that according to documentation you should return new value from `parse` (https://redux-form.com/7.2.1/docs/api/field.md/#-code-format-value-name-gt-formattedvalue-code-optional-)

**UPD**
Example with `type='string'` and `normalize` LC. - https://codesandbox.io/s/x7n01yvj5z

Comment: This doesn't make a difference.  I tried parsing / filtering with a regex on both the parse and normalize lifecycle hooks, but unless the input field has an initial value, you can enter e, + and - into the number field.  
It is as if redux form doesn't recognize these inputs.

Comment: You can find an example there https://codesandbox.io/s/x7n01yvj5z
Note: I've changed type from number to string, because `normalize` handles input by itself

Comment: I wanted to use the number input to show the user a numeric keypad on mobile devices - this gets lost when using input type text.

I've even thought about rendering different components (number and text) depending on mobile vs desktop device.

I'm more concerned why Redux Form allows this on the first character?  As if it doesn't pick up that a key was pressed.

Comment: `input type="number"` allows it, not Redux Form. If you didn't specify any additional parse/normalize function Redux Form just handle raw changes. So as numeric input allows this syntax it will be allowed with redux form

Comment: Yes, I get that, but the problem is that the parse/normalize functions aren't even called if it is entered as the first character.  After that you can enter any combination of numbers, e's, +'s and -'s without ever triggering these lifecycle hooks.
Check my original question.  It even thinks the field is empty, as if there is no value in it.

Comment: Strange behaviour. Try to read this article - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178556/phone-numeric-keyboard-for-text-input. Maybe you'll find a way to force numeric keyboard for text inputs

Comment: This worked for `boolean` types as well: `parse={value => value === 'true'}`
+1

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have solved this problem,

```
<Field
    name="age"
    type="text"
    pattern="[0-9]*"
    inputMode="numeric"
    component={renderField}
    label="Age"
    validate={[required]}
    warn={tooOld}
    normalize={ val => (val || "").replace(/[^\d]/g, "") }
/>
```

so basically `type="text"`, `pattern="[0-9]*"` and `inputMode="numeric"` are required to accept all input values yet forcing the browsers to trigger numeric keypad. Remove the `number` validation from `validate` and lastly use the redux-from's `normalize` api to manipulate input values.