# Chrome android keyboard doesn't reflect inputmode when changing the type property field

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome

the `inputmode` seems to be ignored by chrome on Android device when changing the input `type` attribute.

Sample example of the code

```
class InputApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        mask: true
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Entry</h2>
        <input type={this.state.mask? "password": "text"} onFocus={() => {this.setState({mask: false})}} onBlur={() => {this.setState({mask: true})}} inputMode="numeric" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<InputApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3qhyjbgv/21/

While having an input that mask the value when blurred, the `inputmode` seems to be ignored by chrome on Android device. in chrome on IOS, it's actually working as expected

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Can this be about your keyboard settings on your android device? I tried your code on my android device and normally I don't have numbers on my keyboard but when I click the input area, number row appears on top of my keyboard.
I don't have a numeric keyboard on my phone so it always adds a number row on top of my keyboard.

So I would say that input mode doesn't get ignored, but the reason why it isn't working as you expect may be your device's keyboard. Can you try it on a different android device?

You've probably checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178556/phone-numeric-keyboard-for-text-input) before but if you haven't maybe some of these solutions can work for you.

Comment: The issue is not the number row not appearing, the whole keyboard should be numerical. 
if you remove type changes of the input, it will properly be reflected
FYI, on IOS you can get the correct behaviour for this one