# HTML input type number that should allowed only number not special character like , . and - and applicable for otp and mobile number both

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to take input from the user as a mobile number, but when the user tries to enter a number keyboard opens with a special character, I just want the special character not seen there. I have an example for you guys

My Keyboard where I'm getting challenged,

**my Code**

```
          <mat-form-field class="col-12" appearance="outline" subscriptSizing="dynamic">
            <mat-label>Mobile Number</mat-label>
            <input type="number" matInput formControlName="MobileNumber">
            <span matPrefix style="font-size: 1rem; position: relative; left: 5px">
              +91&nbsp;
            </span>
            <button mat-icon-button matSuffix>
              <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

[image]

I researched but I didn't get a solution on it and I have also example how I want,

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phone: numeric keyboard for text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178556/phone-numeric-keyboard-for-text-input)

Comment: Yes for phone number but with input type number

Comment: Would a virtual keyboard like this (the keys you want) solve your problem? https://ibb.co/wwfg8jM

Comment: Yes, you are right i can solve that problem using a virtual keyboard, did you see the second image of the keyboard? it's similar to the first one just remove unnecessary characters like , . and - so it makes it easy for to user to put input without confusion btw second image is of an axis bank while I'm trying to put OTP, I didn't think axis bank dev uses virtual keyboard there in second image.

Comment: Some possible solutions are already present in the comments, but I'd just like to point out possible non-UI issues: user might still be able to paste the invalid characters (skipping the UI options altogether) or use Postman or any similar platform to hit your api endpoint with unacceptable data. So you should probably do an api-side validation too, along with custom in-app validation upon input being changed. That's all regardless of your UI solution for keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

you can do change with your html and adding some java script like that:

```
<form>
    <div class="col-12">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" subscriptSizing="dynamic">
        <mat-label>Mobile Number</mat-label>
        <input type="tel" id="mobileNumberInput" matInput>
        <span matPrefix style="font-size: 1rem; position: relative; left: 5px">
          +91&nbsp;
        </span>
        <button mat-icon-button matSuffix>
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      const mobileNumberInput = document.getElementById('mobileNumberInput');

      mobileNumberInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
        // Remove any non-numeric characters
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
      });
    });
  </script>
```

hope this can help you