# Opening numeric/tel keyboard on HTML date input

Tags: html

Is there a way to open the tel/numeric keyboard for HTML `date` input?

It currently opens the date picker, but I want to exchange this behaviour with numeric keyboard opening.

Edit: type `date` with `inputmode` set to either `numeric` or `tel` does not work

Thanks

Comment: You want an `eventListener` with `e.preventDefault()`. And https://stackoverflow.com/a/31619311/2569323 .

Comment: @deEr. It's not an answer I'm looking for. I still want the displayed date to be formatted as date in the input itself. Changing the type of the input to `number` removes this formatted date display

Comment: I see. https://css-tricks.com/finger-friendly-numerical-inputs-with-inputmode/ This?  Perhaps just hide it.

Comment: @deEr. I edited the original question

Comment: Probably not doable without Javascript (with a hidden numeric input field, for example). Also be careful with behavior differences between browsers, input methods are even less reliable than usual.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, the only solution I see is redirecting the focus to a hidden numeric field, and translating inputs back into the date picker. Here's a proof-of-concept:

```js
date.onfocus = date.onclick = e => {
    // Redirect focus to numeric field.
    e.preventDefault();
    date_hidden.focus();
};
date_hidden.addEventListener('input', e => {
    // Start with 10102000 (2000-10-10) and replace digits from the numeric input.
    const date_numbers = date_hidden.value + '10102000'.slice(date_hidden.value.length);
    // Reformat as ISO date and set value in the main input.
    // Note that it must always be a valid date, or you'll get
    // the placeholder value 'dd/mm/yyyy'.
    date.value = `${date_numbers.slice(4, 8)}-${date_numbers.slice(2, 4)}-${date_numbers.slice(0, 2)}`;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Date input by number</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="date" id="date" value="2000-10-10">
    <input type="tel" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="8" id="date_hidden">
</body>
</html>
```

However I'd suggest against this line, since you'd have to implement your own error handling, localization (currently assumed to be dd/mm/yyyy), and the intermediary value must always be a valid date (currently 2000-10-10), which can be confusing.

There's probably no native solution, since control of input elements is limited in HTML or Javascript. The date picker is especially problematic, since it's not implemented the same (or at all) everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, there is too much to consider which native date picker does under the hood. Thanks anyways